# Number Theory Problem involving fractional part of a number

Tags: number-theory

If

$x = ( 9 + 4 \sqrt {5} )^{48}$

where $x = [x] + f$, where $[x]$ is he integral part of $x$ , and $x$ is its fractional part

How do I go about finding the value of $x(1-f)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: loot at $(9+4\sqrt{5})^2+(9-4\sqrt{5})^2$ and $(9+4\sqrt{5})^3+(9-4\sqrt{5})^3$.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is its fractional part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Imagine* expanding $A=(9+4\sqrt{5})^{48}+(9-4\sqrt{5})^{48}$ using the Binomial Theorem. The terms that involve odd powers of $\sqrt{5}$ cancel, so $A$ is an integer.

Note that $(9-4\sqrt{5})^{48}$ is positive and close to $0$. It follows that the integer part of $(9+4\sqrt{5})^{48}$ is $A-1$, so the fractional part $f$ is $1-(9-4\sqrt{5})^{48}$. Now we have a nice expression for $1-f$. Multiply by $x$, using the fact that $(9+4\sqrt{5})(9-4\sqrt{5})=1$.

**Remark:** The numbers $9+4\sqrt{5}$ and $9-4\sqrt{5}$ are *conjugates*. Whenever $9+4\sqrt{5}$ has a problem, $9-4\sqrt{5}$  can be reliably counted on for help.

Comment: " It follows that the integer part is A-1 ". Could you explain this ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks anyways :D

Comment: For everyone else A= [x] + f1 + f2.    Now f1 + f2 has to be integral, since A is an integer.  Now since f2 and f1 are both lesser than 1 f1 And f1 + f2 is an integer. It has to be equal to 1

Comment: Since you got it, explanation is probably unnecessary. The integer $A$ is $x$ plus a tiny bit.  So $x$ is a tiny bit under $A$. So when we take the integer part of $x$, we go down almost $1$, to the first integer below $A$, which is $A-1$.